# Tensorflow error calling model.fit after load_model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a small, simple neural net for a basic problem of regulating a motor's speed. I want to be able to save the model and exit the program, then load it later and resume training.

Here's the relevant code:

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(InputLayer(2))
self.model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dense(9, activation='linear')) 
self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

# ... Loop for training and Evaluation (Deep Q Learner) ... 
learn(self.model)

self.model.save('motor_model', save_format='tf')
```

Now after it's trained I want to be able to load the model and continue training

```
self.model = models.load_model('motor_model', compile=False)

# ... Loop for training and Evaluation (Deep Q Learner) ... 
learn(self.model)
```

The first time I run the model it works fine. However, after saving and loading the model it does not. Upon loading the model I am able to call the predict function:

```
prediction = self.model.predict(currentInput)
```

However, It fails when I call the predict function:

```
self.model.fit(self.input, target_vec.reshape(-1, 9), epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

The error I get is:

> 2019-12-07 07:22:00.762174: W tensorflow/c/c_api.cc:326] Operation
>   '{name:'sequential/dense/StatefulPartitionedCall'
>   id:33 op device:{} def:{{{node
>   sequential/dense/StatefulPartitionedCall}} =
>   StatefulPartitionedCall[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT
>   _RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _gradient_op_type="PartitionedCall-298", conf
>   ig="",
>   config_proto="\n\007\n\003CPU\020\001\n\007\n\003GPU\020\0002\002J\0008\001",
>   executor_type="", f=__forward_re
>   stored_function_body_509[]](input_1, dense/kernel, dense/bias)}}' was
>   changed by setting attribute after it was run b
>   y a session. This mutation will have no effect, and will trigger an
>   error in the future. Either don't modify nodes af
>   ter running them or create a new session. 2019-12-07 07:22:03.320478:
>   W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:299] Sets are not currently
>   considered sequences, but th
>   is may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1363, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1346, in _run_fn
>       self._extend_graph()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1386, in _extend_graph
>       tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node
>   'training/Adam/gradients/gradients/sequential/dens
>   e_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall': Connecting to
>   invalid output 1 of source node sequential/dense_1/S
>   tatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ct2.py", line 47, in
>   
>       leftController.to_position(target, overrideAction)   File "/opt/mowzr/motor_controller.py", line 94, in to_position
>       self.model.fit(self.prevInput, target_vec.reshape(-1, 9), epochs=1, verbose=0)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 766, in fit
>       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py",
>   line 680, in
>   fit
>       steps_name='steps_per_epoch')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py",
>   line 275, in
>   model_iteration
>       model.reset_metrics()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 953, in reset_m
>   etrics
>       m.reset_states()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/metrics.py",
>   line 209, in reset_states
>       K.batch_set_value([(v, 0) for v in self.variables])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py",
>   line 3343, in batch_set_valu
>   e
>       get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py",
>   line 490, in get_session
>       _initialize_variables(session)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py",
>   line 905, in _initialize_var
>   iables
>       [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 956, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1179, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1357, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1382, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node
>   'training/Adam/gradients/gradients/sequential/dens
>   e_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall': Connecting to
>   invalid output 1 of source node sequential/dense_1/S
>   tatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1363, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1346, in _run_fn
>       self._extend_graph()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1386, in _extend_graph
>       tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node
>   'training/Adam/gradients/gradients/sequential/dens
>   e_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall': Connecting to
>   invalid output 1 of source node sequential/dense_1/S
>   tatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ct2.py", line 53, in
>   
>       leftController.saveModel()   File "/opt/mowzr/motor_controller.py", line 116, in saveModel
>       self.model.save('motor_model', save_format='tf')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py",
>   line 986, in save
>       signatures, options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py",
>   line 115, in save_model
>       signatures, options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py",
>   line 74, in
>   save
>       save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py",
>   line 924, in save
>       object_saver.save(utils_impl.get_variables_path(export_dir))   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/util.py",
>   line 1161, in save
>       session = get_session()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/util.py",
>   line 71, in get_ses
>   sion
>       session = keras_backend.get_session()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py",
>   line 490, in get_session
>       _initialize_variables(session)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py",
>   line 905, in _initialize_var
>   iables
>       [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 956, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1179, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1357, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1382, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Node
>   'training/Adam/gradients/gradients/sequential/dens
>   e_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall': Connecting to
>   invalid output 1 of source node sequential/dense_1/S
>   tatefulPartitionedCall which has 1 outputs.

Comment: Did you try to save and load just the weights instead of the whole model?

Comment: Furthermore, it seems to me that the code is in Keras not in Tensorflow.

Comment: @Chris_toah yes Keras with tensorflow backend. I can try just loading weights

Comment: what I mean is to use Keras function save_weights and load_weights correspondingly instead of using directly save and load.

Comment: @ChrisTosh save_weights/load_weights did work for my use case and that's what I'm doing now, though it didn't really answer the question of why save/load_model doesn't work

Comment: Hey @James Suffolk yes you are right, however, from my experience was always more smooth to save the weights and the model in a JSON file instead of using save/load.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

I don't know what exactly produces this error but there is a way to solve it (not a pretty one though). Create the model with the same architecture and just set the weights to the loaded model weights:

```
self.model = self.create_model()
self.model.set_weights(load_model("sample.model").get_weights())
```

Comment: I got  similar error in evaluate function, solved it by replacing load_model with load_weights function.